# Android M Preview 3 emulator Native Browser crash

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-breakpad

I have created an Android emulator with OS(6.0) and when the emulator starts i launch directly the "Browser" app and get a crash.

Here are some logs :

```
W/System(1617): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/arm

E/ActivityThread(1617): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

### WebView Version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011900)
 Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1667 (GpuThread)
SELinux: Loaded file_contexts contexts from /file_contexts.
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk_phone_armv7/generic:6.0/MRA44C/2166767:eng/test-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm'
 pid: 1617, tid: 1667, name: GpuThread  >>> com.android.browser <<<
 signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
 Abort message: '[FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
```

does anyone know something about that?

Please find the tombstone file that contains the full crash log : 
[Tombstone01](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4143gmxj50h3tta/tombstone_01?dl=0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved by checking "Use GPU Host" when creating the emulator.